# Is just a long password more secure than a user/password combination?

Tags: security, passwords

Basically, my question is already in the title.

**The idea is:**

Option 1:
*Password:* XXXXXXXX (8-character)

Option 2:
*Username:* XXXX (4-character)
*Password:* XXXX (4-character)

Should be equally secure, right?

Comment: If a user forgets her/his password, how can (s)he request password reset, in case that only password is used?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more appropriate on http://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a purely theoretical point of view, I would say yes. At first. The number of combinations should equal, if I am not mistaken.

But there are other things to consider.

Firstly, as Alex Shesterov mentioned, you would not have the possibility to change a password for a given user.

Secondly, if two persons use the same password, which is maybe hash-generated, you cannot distinguish these users.

Therefore it is hard to decide if someone is trying to get access by guessing (brute-force) or if multiple users are using the same password. If you have a user/password combination you can count the number of accesses for each user seperately.

Another point is implementation. If you only have the password for identification, you would have to crawl all of you password database for each access, which takes linear time ( O(n) ), which means that a growing user-base would increase the time and effort, which is necessary for each single access.

Lastly, for an attacker it would be only necessary to find just one valid password, instead of a valid user/password combination. Since you cannot distinguish different users, if they may use the same password, this possibly means that an attecker can gain access to the complete system, as all users are equal. Therefore you would need additional means to safely distinguish users wihtin your system.

In the end, I would stick to the user/password combination and change the needed complexity for the password and its length.

**edit:** removed the link to the birthday problem, since it is not applicable, as discussed in the comments.

Comment: How can bday problem possibly affect password entropy?

Comment: Given, that one just wants to have access to the system, one has to get access to one valid password and not to have a valid user/password combination. Since this system has no chance to distinguish any user, because multiple users can have the same password, each password should be equally sufficient. Is that not similar to the problem for hashed password, for which one only needs to have a random password which generates the needed hash? Please correct me, if I am wrong.

Comment: I think you dont consider the fact that the uname and pwd are both 4 chars long compared to 8char pwd only variant. I agree with you in the case that uname can be sth more complex and not length restricted in such way, but we are comparing 4char uname+4char pwd with 8char pwd. I believe the entropy is the same

Comment: You do have a point there. I tried to think about, how the number of valid passwords vs. the number of valid user/password combinations affekt the possibility to randomly get a correct one, but since the sizes are the same, the possibility should be the same. Do you think, since with the single password, there are less (some are used by multiple users), the one-password solution would be actually less likely to be guessed or brute-forced?

Comment: This depends on pwd selection. If pwd is selected randomly, then it cannot be dictionary attacked. A more efficient attack however would be to try all possible unames for each pwd. Once you find that, you no longer have to try that uname for different pwd as unames must be unique. So by finding one uname pwd match, you remove 1/B^4 possibilities and reduce the attack by this factor. When u have 8char pwd and u find one, you know nothing more about the other passwords, so you effectively reduce just 1/B^8 options. B being total number of allowed char values